# Xamarin.Android C# layout_weight error: Must specify a unit, such as "px" (Intellisense?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

A snippet of my layout:

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:text="@string/moreInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight= "1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/moreInfo" />
```

I get an IntelliSense error: Must specify a unit, such as "px" for every instance of android:layout_weight in the file. I've tried adding WeightSum to the LinearLayout and changing from int to float (though still in quotes) but the error persists.

The odd thing (to me, at least) is that I can still build/run my code on the emulator.  My guess is that it's something in IntelliSense, and I don't like outstanding errors, even if they're erroneous...

Using VS2019 Community.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue.It may be the IntelliSense  issue.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019, Version 16.7.2 with Resharper. I can reproduce those problems.

Comment: Using 16.7.2 version 4.8.03761, updated today, I get an error not in Intellisense but in the Error list when I build. Still the app runs well. Probably linked to this error: on layout_height="0dp" in a vertical LinearLayout I get this error: Suspicious size, this will make the view invisible, probably intended for 'layout_width*.

Comment: with respect to my previous comment: I closed the XML file in the project, closed the project, reopened the project and build the app: no more errors.

Comment: Reopened the XML and now I see Intellisense errors and also get build errors.

Comment: Same error in VS 2022 for Mac for attribute android:alpha

Comment: Nothing like this surprises me.  This Xamarin/Android/Maui garbage is dreadful enough as it is without extra rubbish actually embedded in it.  God help me survive this excrement before I die ...

Answer (score 10):

this is a bug in Visual Studio and its new Analyzers. Other than the annoyance of it showing up in the error list it shouldn't affect the app build or running it.

Sincerely the lame developer that wrote the bug :)

PS, I'm really sorry for the trouble and am working on fixing it right now.

PPS, I'll make sure to add a unit test.

Update: A fix is in and should land in one of the next couple 16.9 previews

Comment: I have just updated my VS Mac and still see this issue. Has the fix been released yet?

Comment: @sshaw February 2021, many more versions of VS2019 later, bug is still there....

Comment: Updated Visual Studio to version 16.9.2. The bug has been fixed.

Comment: Wow.  Very cool hearing from the coder involved.  I actually like seeing bugs in Big Boy code cause then I don't feel so bad about mine.  : - )

Comment: This does seem to have been fixed for `android:layout_weight`, but I've just run into the same issue (exact same IntelliSense "error" message, at least) with `android:rotation` (on VS 2019 16.11.10)

Comment: Still there in 17.7.1 ... <= beset by Chimps

Answer (score 3):

Same error for me since i update 16.7.1, it's happening in each axml files.
I believed it's due to update so i wait the next update but it's always occured in 16.7.2.

Comment: Not only this when I open a layout it adds some random junk into it and then tell me that it cannot compile because of the junk. So I have to remove those junk elements by pressing Ctrl + Z, so that it can compile. I have noticed that after the update 16.7.0, VS has been so much democratic ;-)

Comment: Just leaving a comment here: I'm still having this issue in 16.7.5

Comment: still have it in 16.8.3

Answer (score 3):

**Please note that this solution is just a half measure until this issue is fixed.**

Solution that worked for me was to disable **IntelliSense Analysis** in VS.

Simply go to Tools/Options/Text Editor/Android XML/Advanced and uncheck **Enable layout diagnostics** in **Analysis**

Backside of this approach is that IntelliSense does not check your code spelling at all.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried your code in my VS 2019 Community and no IntelliSense errors for me.

Could be IntelliSense cache?

1. Close VS
2. Delete .vs folder in solution root directory
3. Start VS

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help.  When I open the project and build/rebuild/run it, the errors don't show up.  As soon as I open the .axml file, they appear in the error list.  Is there an XML parser in IntelliSense?  If so, could this be a configuration setting?